# Too small font in xelatex (for Garamond Libre)

Tags: fonts, xetex

I used EB Garamond, then decided to try [Garamond Libre](https://dbmiller.org/type/garamond-libre.html). I didn’t change any other parameters, but in the document the font decreased significantly. Why, and how to fix it?
In LibreOffice, he looks even bigger than first

[image: EB Garamond]
[image: Garamond Libre]

If you remove

```
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchUppercase}
```

all font sizes are normalized

XeLaTeX is

```
\documentclass[a4paper, draft, openright, 12pt]{extreport}
\usepackage[left=20mm,right=10mm,top=17mm,bottom=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[main=russian,english]{babel}    %% загружает пакет многоязыковой вёрстки
                   %% подготавливает загрузку шрифтов Open Type, True Type и др.
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{titlesec,titletoc}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{enumitem}
%\usepackage{balance}
\usepackage{metalogo}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage[final]{microtype}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=black]{hyperref}

% -------------- Настраваем шрифты -----------------------------
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchUppercase}
\usepackage{setspace}
%\setmainfont[StylisticSet=1]{EBGaramond12-Regular} % Основной шрифт текста

\onehalfspacing

\setsansfont [UprightFont = *]{Fregat}  % Шрифт замечаний
\newfontfamily{\ivry}{Linux Biolinum O}  % Для слов на иврите
\newfontfamily{\fyanone}{Fregat}
%\newfontfamily{\chn}{Cocogoose Pro Block Gradient}  % Шрифт для оглавления
\newfontfamily{\chn}{Fregat}  % Шрифт для оглавления


% --------------- Формат для оглавлений ------------------------
\titleformat
    {\chapter} % command
    [display]  % shape
    {\Huge\bfseries} % format
    {
    \raggedleft
    {
        \fyanone\bfseries\fontsize{48pt}{48pt}\selectfont Часть
            \chn\fontsize{64pt}{20pt}\selectfont\thechapter}
    } % label
    {-6pt} % sep
    {
        \titlerule[2.5pt]
        \vspace{1.2pt}
        \titlerule[1.2pt]
    } % before-code

\titleformat{\section}[display]
    {\Large\sffamily}
    {}{}{\uppercase}
  [
    \vspace{-12pt}%
    \rule{36mm}{0.5pt}
    \vspace{4pt}
  ] %

\titleformat{\subsection}[wrap]
{\bfseries\sffamily}
{}{}{}[]

\titlespacing{\subsection}
{8pc}{1.5ex}{1pc}
%------------------- Содержание ---------------------------
\titlecontents{chapter}
[2.5em]
{\addvspace{20pt}\filcenter}
{\Large\MakeUppercase{часть\ \thecontentslabel}\ \sffamily\itshape\bfseries\Large}
{\sffamily\itshape\bfseries\Large}
{}
[\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}\hspace*{8pt}]

\titlecontents{section}
[0pt]
{\addvspace{1pt}}
{}
{\normalsize\sffamily\uppercase}
{\titlerule*[4pt]{.}\contentspage}

\titlecontents{subsection}
[25pt]
{\addvspace{1pt}}
{}
{\sffamily\bfseries}
{\titlerule*[4pt]{.}\contentspage}

% ---------------- Счетчики ------------------------
\newcounter{qenum}
\newcounter{q1}


\newcommand{\qa}{\addtocounter{q1}{1}\arabic{q1})\ }

\newenvironment{quest}{%
 \setcounter{qenum}{0}
 \sffamily
 \vspace{12pt}
 \centerline{\textbf{Вопросы для размышления:}}
 \vspace*{-6pt}
 \centerline{\rule{120pt}{0.5pt}}
 \vspace*{-12pt}
 \small
 \begin{enumerate} \leftskip=0.5em \rightskip=0.5em \parskip-1em \itemsep=1.3em \parsep=0em
 \item[]}
 {\end{enumerate}}

% ---------------- Основная информация книги ----------------------



% ================ Настройка некоторых параметров =================|
\sloppy %------------------------------ Красивое формирование строк|
\parindent=18pt %------------------------------Отступ первой строки|
\setlength{\columnsep}{14pt} %------------Растояние между колонками|
%\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.005pt} %----------Линия между колонками|
% -----------------------------------------------------------------|
%\tolerance=600
%\emergencystretch=2pt
\hfuzz=0.9pt
\doublehyphendemerits=9000000
% ---------------- Двухколоночное формирование текста -------------
\twocolumn
\clubpenalty=10000
\widowpenalty=10000
\raggedbottom
\hyphenpenalty=800
\righthyphenmin=2

\makeatletter
\def\qitem{\begingroup\catcode`\^^M=12 \qitem@}
\bgroup\catcode`\^^M=12 %
   \gdef\qitem@#1^^M{\addtocounter{qenum}{1}\item[\textbf{В.\arabic{qenum}:}] #1?\endgroup}%
\egroup
\makeatother

\linespread{0.93}

\ULdepth = 0.2em
\begin{document}

% ================ Подключаем нужные файлы ========================
\setmainfont{EB Garamond 12 Regular} % Основной шрифт текста
\section*{EB Garamond 12 Regular}
Lorem ipsum – псевдо-латинский текст, который используется для веб дизайна, типографии, оборудования, и распечатки вместо английского текста для того, чтобы сделать ударение не на содержание, а на элементы дизайна. Такой текст также называется как заполнитель. Это очень удобный инструмент для моделей (макетов). Он помогает выделить визуальные элементы в документе или презентации, например текст, шрифт или разметка. Lorem ipsum по большей части является элементом латинского текста классического автора и философа Цицерона. Слова и буквы были заменены добавлением или сокращением элементов, поэтому будет совсем неразумно пытаться передать содержание; это не гениально, не правильно, используется даже не понятный латинский. Хотя Lorem ipsum напоминает классический латинский, вы не найдете никакого смысла в сказанном. Поскольку текст Цицерона не содержит буквы K, W, или Z, что чуждо для латинского, эти буквы, а также многие другие часто вставлены в случайном порядке, чтобы скопировать тексты различных Европейских языков, поскольку диграфы не встречаются в оригинальных текстах.
\section*{Garamond Libre}
\setmainfont{Garamond Libre}
Lorem ipsum – псевдо-латинский текст, который используется для веб дизайна, типографии, оборудования, и распечатки вместо английского текста для того, чтобы сделать ударение не на содержание, а на элементы дизайна. Такой текст также называется как заполнитель. Это очень удобный инструмент для моделей (макетов). Он помогает выделить визуальные элементы в документе или презентации, например текст, шрифт или разметка. Lorem ipsum по большей части является элементом латинского текста классического автора и философа Цицерона. Слова и буквы были заменены добавлением или сокращением элементов, поэтому будет совсем неразумно пытаться передать содержание; это не гениально, не правильно, используется даже не понятный латинский. Хотя Lorem ipsum напоминает классический латинский, вы не найдете никакого смысла в сказанном. Поскольку текст Цицерона не содержит буквы K, W, или Z, что чуждо для латинского, эти буквы, а также многие другие часто вставлены в случайном порядке, чтобы скопировать тексты различных Европейских языков, поскольку диграфы не встречаются в оригинальных текстах.
% =================================================================

% ---------------- Содержание книги -------------------------------
{При подготовке данного издания была использована технология \XeLaTeX}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What is the code you ran? A small test document is enough to illustrate the problem.

Comment: You might have to contact the font designer. Use `Scale=1` as a workaround, in the meantime.

Comment: @Cicada, I added TeX document in the description

Comment: This is not a *small* test document. It can't even be tested as you are using \input.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, You can now try it. I replaced the example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MatchUppercase uses the cap-height (fontdimen 8) to calculate the scale factor. And this fontdimen is quite large for your font. The only advice one can give is not to use `MatchUppercase` for it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
\setmainfont{EB Garamond} x \rule{1ex}{1ex} \rule{\fontdimen8\font}{\fontdimen8\font} 
\the\fontdimen5\font, \the\fontdimen8\font

\setmainfont{Garamond Libre} x \rule{1ex}{1ex} \rule{\fontdimen8\font}{\fontdimen8\font}
\the\fontdimen5\font, \the\fontdimen8\font

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The font dimensions of Garamond Libre appear to be declared incorrectly.  If you load it with `Scale = 1.0`, however, it works:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, openright, 12pt]{extreport}
\usepackage[left=20mm,right=10mm,top=17mm,bottom=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[main=russian,english]{babel}    %% загружает пакет многоязыковой вёрстки
                   %% подготавливает загрузку шрифтов Open Type, True Type и др.
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{titlesec,titletoc}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumitem}
%\usepackage{balance}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{metalogo}
%\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=black]{hyperref}

% -------------- Настраваем шрифты -----------------------------
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchUppercase}
\usepackage{setspace}

\setmainfont[StylisticSet=1]{EBGaramond12}[
  Scale = 1.0 ,
  UprightFont = *-Regular ] % Основной шрифт текста

\newfontfamily\GaramondLibre{Garamond Libre}[
  Scale = 1.0 ,
  Ligatures = {Common, TeX}]

\onehalfspacing

%\setsansfont{Fregat}  % Шрифт замечаний

% --------------- Формат для оглавлений ------------------------
\titleformat
    {\chapter} % command
    [display]  % shape
    {\Huge\bfseries} % format
    {
    \raggedleft
    {
        \fyanone\bfseries\fontsize{48pt}{48pt}\selectfont Часть
            \chn\fontsize{64pt}{20pt}\selectfont\thechapter}
    } % label
    {-6pt} % sep
    {
        \titlerule[2.5pt]
        \vspace{1.2pt}
        \titlerule[1.2pt]
    } % before-code

\titleformat{\section}[display]
    {\Large\sffamily}
    {}{}{\uppercase}
  [
    \vspace{-12pt}%
    \rule{36mm}{0.5pt}
    \vspace{4pt}
  ] %

\titleformat{\subsection}[wrap]
{\bfseries\sffamily}
{}{}{}[]

\titlespacing{\subsection}
{8pc}{1.5ex}{1pc}
%------------------- Содержание ---------------------------
\titlecontents{chapter}
[2.5em]
{\addvspace{20pt}\filcenter}
{\Large\MakeUppercase{часть\ \thecontentslabel}\ \sffamily\itshape\bfseries\Large}
{\sffamily\itshape\bfseries\Large}
{}
[\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}\hspace*{8pt}]

\titlecontents{section}
[0pt]
{\addvspace{1pt}}
{}
{\normalsize\sffamily\uppercase}
{\titlerule*[4pt]{.}\contentspage}

\titlecontents{subsection}
[25pt]
{\addvspace{1pt}}
{}
{\sffamily\bfseries}
{\titlerule*[4pt]{.}\contentspage}

% ---------------- Счетчики ------------------------
\newcounter{qenum}
\newcounter{q1}


\newcommand{\qa}{\addtocounter{q1}{1}\arabic{q1})\ }

\newenvironment{quest}{%
 \setcounter{qenum}{0}
 \sffamily
 \vspace{12pt}
 \centerline{\textbf{Вопросы для размышления:}}
 \vspace*{-6pt}
 \centerline{\rule{120pt}{0.5pt}}
 \vspace*{-12pt}
 \small
 \begin{enumerate} \leftskip=0.5em \rightskip=0.5em \parskip-1em \itemsep=1.3em \parsep=0em
 \item[]}
 {\end{enumerate}}

% ---------------- Основная информация книги ----------------------



% ================ Настройка некоторых параметров =================|
\sloppy %------------------------------ Красивое формирование строк|
\parindent=18pt %------------------------------Отступ первой строки|
\setlength{\columnsep}{14pt} %------------Растояние между колонками|
%\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.005pt} %----------Линия между колонками|
% -----------------------------------------------------------------|
%\tolerance=600
%\emergencystretch=2pt
\hfuzz=0.9pt
\doublehyphendemerits=9000000
% ---------------- Двухколоночное формирование текста -------------
\twocolumn
\clubpenalty=10000
\widowpenalty=10000
\raggedbottom
\hyphenpenalty=800
\righthyphenmin=2

\makeatletter
\def\qitem{\begingroup\catcode`\^^M=12 \qitem@}
\bgroup\catcode`\^^M=12 %
   \gdef\qitem@#1^^M{\addtocounter{qenum}{1}\item[\textbf{В.\arabic{qenum}:}] #1?\endgroup}%
\egroup
\makeatother

\linespread{0.93}

\ULdepth = 0.2em
\begin{document}

% ================ Подключаем нужные файлы ========================
\normalfont % Основной шрифт текста
\section*{EB Garamond 12 Regular}
Lorem ipsum---псевдо-латинский текст, который используется для веб дизайна, типографии, оборудования, и распечатки вместо английского текста для того, чтобы сделать ударение не на содержание, а на элементы дизайна. Такой текст также называется как заполнитель. Это очень удобный инструмент для моделей (макетов). Он помогает выделить визуальные элементы в документе или презентации, например текст, шрифт или разметка. Lorem ipsum по большей части является элементом латинского текста классического автора и философа Цицерона. Слова и буквы были заменены добавлением или сокращением элементов, поэтому будет совсем неразумно пытаться передать содержание; это не гениально, не правильно, используется даже не понятный латинский. Хотя Lorem ipsum напоминает классический латинский, вы не найдете никакого смысла в сказанном. Поскольку текст Цицерона не содержит буквы K, W, или Z, что чуждо для латинского, эти буквы, а также многие другие часто вставлены в случайном порядке, чтобы скопировать тексты различных Европейских языков, поскольку диграфы не встречаются в оригинальных текстах.

\GaramondLibre
\section*{Garamond Libre}
Lorem ipsum---псевдо-латинский текст, который используется для веб дизайна, типографии, оборудования, и распечатки вместо английского текста для того, чтобы сделать ударение не на содержание, а на элементы дизайна. Такой текст также называется как заполнитель. Это очень удобный инструмент для моделей (макетов). Он помогает выделить визуальные элементы в документе или презентации, например текст, шрифт или разметка. Lorem ipsum по большей части является элементом латинского текста классического автора и философа Цицерона. Слова и буквы были заменены добавлением или сокращением элементов, поэтому будет совсем неразумно пытаться передать содержание; это не гениально, не правильно, используется даже не понятный латинский. Хотя Lorem ipsum напоминает классический латинский, вы не найдете никакого смысла в сказанном. Поскольку текст Цицерона не содержит буквы K, W, или Z, что чуждо для латинского, эти буквы, а также многие другие часто вставлены в случайном порядке, чтобы скопировать тексты различных Европейских языков, поскольку диграфы не встречаются в оригинальных текстах.
% =================================================================

% ---------------- Содержание книги -------------------------------
{При подготовке данного издания была использована технология \LuaLaTeX}

\end{document}
```

[image: EB Garamond/Garamond Libre sample]

I took the liberty of removing obsolete 8-bit font encodings, correcting the command to load EB Garamond 12 so that the rest of the font family works, updating `color` to `xcolor`, removing the `draft` option and compiling in LuaLaTeX so that font expansion would work, and some other minor changes.

if you want to change fonts in the middle of the document, it’s better to define a font family (as you do in the commented-out parts of your MWE) than to redefine `\setmainfont`, or you can use the `\fontspec` command.